# How to tell the main thread that a URLSessionDataTask has finished

Tags: swift, multithreading, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

Using Swift 4, I have this code that attempts a POST request to a REST API:

```
spinner.startAnimation(self)
btnOk.isEnabled = false
btnCancel.isEnabled = false

attemptPost()

spinner.stopAnimation(self)
btnOk.isEnabled = true
btnCancel.isEnabled = true
```

The function that does this (`Constants` and `Request` are classes that I created that create the request objects and hold frequently used data):

```
func attemptPost() {
    let url = Constants.SERVICE_URL + "account/post"
    let body: [String : Any] =
        ["firstName": txtFirstName.stringValue,
        "lastName": txtLastName.stringValue,
        "email": txtEmail.stringValue,
        "password": txtPassword.stringValue];
    let req = Request.create(urlExtension: url, httpVerb: Constants.HTTP_POST, jsonBody: body)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req) { data, response, err in
        guard let data = data, err == nil else {
            // error
            return
        }

        if let resp = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) {
            // success
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Since the task that does this runs asynchronously, there is no sequential way that I can update the UI once the call to `attemptPost()` returns. And since the UI components are on the main thread, I can't directly update the components from the task that makes the request.

In C# it works the same way; there is a `BackgroundWorker` class in which you can safely update the UI components to avoid a "Cross-thread operation not valid" error.

I'm trying to find an example that accomplishes more or less the same thing, in which a "wait" state is established, the task runs, and upon task completion, the main thread is notified that the task is done so that the wait state can be changed.

But I'm still having trouble understanding how this all comes together in Swift. I've looked around and seen information about the handlers that are invoked from within `URLSessionDataTask` and stuff about GCD, but I'm still not able to connect the dots.

And is GCD even relevant here since the `URLSessionDataTask` task is asynchronous to begin with?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly you might try this solution:

```
spinner.startAnimation(self)
btnOk.isEnabled = false
btnCancel.isEnabled = false

attemptPost { (success) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        spinner.stopAnimation(self)
        btnOk.isEnabled = true
        btnCancel.isEnabled = true
    }

   // UI wise, eventually you can do something with 'success'
}

func attemptPost(_ completion:@escaping (Bool)->())
    let url = Constants.SERVICE_URL + "account/post"
    let body: [String : Any] =
        ["firstName": txtFirstName.stringValue,
         "lastName": txtLastName.stringValue,
         "email": txtEmail.stringValue,
         "password": txtPassword.stringValue];
    let req = Request.create(urlExtension: url, httpVerb: Constants.HTTP_POST, jsonBody: body)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req) { data, response, err in
        guard let data = data, err == nil else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        if let resp = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) {
            completion(true)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

---

so the idea is executing from `attemptPost` a block which will run asynchronously into the main thread your UI stuff

Comment: That worked! The only change I needed to make to the function signature was: `func attemptPost(_ completion:@escaping (Bool)->())`. Otherwise, that's pretty cool. So `completion` is a variable that gets written to when the task completes?

Comment: Hi David, 'completion' is a parameter representing a code block, you may check here about Closures: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html